# convert JSON to Object by Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have specific JSON. for example:

```
legs":{
    "dir0":{},
    "dir1":{}
}
```

Parent class:

```
public class Record{
    @JsonProperty("legs")
    private Leg legs;
    //getter setter
}
```

How I can define my class `Leg` to get `List<Dir>` or `Map<String,Dir>`?
where `Dir` contains properties of dir0, dir1...

Answer (score 0):

I understand my trouble. I have exess class `Leg`. I need to do like this:

```
public class Record{
           @JsonProperty("legs")
           private Map<String,Dir> dirs;
           //getter setter
    }
```